# How to run Vue on port 5173 when using Laravel? - This is the Vite development server that provides Hot Module Replacement

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am learing Laravel, and following a fullstack tutorial. The application is Laravel+Vue.

When I started Laravel on port 8000 with `php artisan serve` it opened as it should. Then I created Vue app inside src folder. It should be started with command `npm run dev` on port 5173. When I open it, I don't see default Vue starting page:

[image]

I only see this:

[image]

How can I start the right server on right port to make frontend of my app?

This is my App.vue:

```
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
    components: { HelloWorld },
    computed: { ...mapState(["user"]) },
};
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Bok</h2>
        <pre>{{ user }}</pre>
    </div>
    <HelloWorld msg="Vite + Vue" />
</template>

<style scoped>
.logo {
    height: 6em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    will-change: filter;
    transition: filter 300ms;
}
.logo:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #646cffaa);
}
.logo.vue:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #42b883aa);
}
</style>
```

And this is my index.js:

```
const { createStore } = require("vuex");

const store = createStore({
  state: { user: { data: { name: "Zura" }, token: null } },
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
  mutations: {},
  modules: {},
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and main problem was that the app was started from the wrong folder. It needs to be started from vue subfolder:

laravel: myapp> `php artisan serve`

**vue: myapp\vue>** `npm run dev`

The second problem was that after opening localhost:5173 nothing was shown: I needed to change `const { createStore } = require("vuex");` to `import { createStore } from "vuex";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you see what you should, im currently working on laravel-vue-vite project and when i installed it i also had Laravel dashboard

To run laravel localy

```
php artisan serve
```

And for vite you run
For localy

```
npm run dev
```

For production

```
npm run build
```

Note that they both should be run at same time in Visual studio code to do that  you need open second terminal so press "+" icon in right top corner of terminal

If you installed laravel with vue your views are stored in resources/js

And routes in routes/web.php

[image]